# Regular expression in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, regex

Regular expression not able to read complete string, only working correct with single character.

```
var abc = "ab";
var patter = /^([a-z0-9A-Z])$/;

 if (patter.test(abc)) {
    console.log('yes');
 } else {
   console.log('no');
}
```

Comment: Your regular expression only matches one character, you need to use a quantifier, see here http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set a quantifier when you don't want just one character.

Add a `*` to match zero or more character (or a `+` if you want to be sure there's at least one character);

```
var patter = /^[a-z0-9A-Z]*$/;
```

Note that I removed the parentheses : they're useless with the `test` method.